# Making paragraph look better when using bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

Hello I am using bootstrap grid and trying to make this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8bf865ea19bb09408e7dd214f1887d24.png))</sub>

That's what I am using to try to get something like this:

The code is inside bootstrap container by the way,

```
<div class="headers">

    <li class="span3">
    <div id="icon-1"></div>
    <span class="head">Experienced</span>
    <p class="paragraph">Brought to you by a well-knowledged developer and designer, that are ready to serve. We deliver one Hell of a product so strap yourself down to your chair and get ready.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
    <div id="icon-2"></div>
    <span class="headweb">Web Development</span>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
    <div id="icon-3"></div>
    <span class="head">UI/UX Design</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

That's the result:

[image: image2]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/351f69ce5b85c9b66a38de96c393750e.png))</sub>

as you see the paragraph looks way different than in the first paragraph, that's because the bootstrap grid span class number is too short, but if I will use span 4, the icon will just mess up to the bottom.

How can I make the paragraphs look a bit of what it looks in the first image?
What is the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: well I don't know much abot bootstrap but can;t you use `text-align: center` for this

Comment: Well it doesn't look right, it goes to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Your text looks a larger than the orig, but that's too simple. Try making a new class, .span3wide and in your stylesheet increase the size, reduce the padding/margin. Also, add margin:0 auto; to #icon-1 to centre.